# bash スクリプトでエラー: 単項演算子が予期されます。

Tags: linux, bash

下記の内容をCentOS7にて実行した所、`3行:　[:　0:　単項演算子が予期されます` と表示されてしまいます。（IPアドレスの部分は伏字にしてありますが、実際にはあてはめます）

ネットに上がっていた通り、ここをさらに `[]` でくくってみたのですが、`条件二項演算子が予期されます` と表示されて実行できません。

どうすればこのシェルスクリプトを実行できますでしょうか。

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while [ $count !=100 ]
do
curl http://x.x.x.x/index.html --interface "x.x.x.1"
curl http://x.x.x.x/index.html --interface "x.x.x.2"
curl http://x.x.x.x/index.html --interface "x.x.x.3"
count=$(()$count + 1)
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

比較演算子 `!=` と `100` の間にスペースが無いのが原因じゃないでしょうか。
正しくは

```sh
while [ $count != 100 ]
```